# Can I use Google Sheets to connect to an API (using OAuth2) OR can I send a hourly scheduled response from Postman to Google Sheets?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, postman

**Goal**
I want to connect to an API (to a web service called Sharesight which monitors stock portfolios) so that I can pull my portfolio returns every hour (during business days) into the Google Sheets.  Then I will use Google Sheets to send an email to me every hour.

The exact process doesn't have to be like that, but essentially I want to pull some data from account and email it to me.  I plan to use Google Sheets because I will want to choose specific things from the JSON so I thought that's an easy way to set up formulas, etc.

**Caveat**
I know what an API is but I have never played around with them before so I'm learning as I go.

**What I've tried...in Google Sheets**
I tried using Google Sheets to write some code (I think it is Javascript) to connect to Sharesight (using all the client ID, client secret, authorise token URI, access token URI, etc.)  I think where I failed is that I need to specify a 'Redirect URI' which in the Sharesight notes, it says for local tests, I can use "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".  I tried this anyway, but I think I can't since I'm not doing a local test.

*- So my first stumbling block is...how can I get an Redirect URI
   connected to my Google Sheets?*

**So then, I tried Postman**
I just googled API tool and found this so thought I'd give it a shot, because I haven't actually even connected to the API yet.  So fortunately, I got through and it connected fine.  I used a GET thing to my portfolio URL and I had to pass through yesterday's date and today's date as the parameters of the report - which worked fine!

But then I'm thinking, I need to import this into Google Sheets.  Is this actually possible? Within postman, I'm using their redirect URI which is why I think I was able to progress further (https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback) - however I then need additional steps to push it through.

But then some other questions arise:

- Can Postman actually run every hour and 'do something'? Does it have
  a scheduling ability?
- Can it run while my computer is not turned on? If not, then it's
  pretty useless to me (unless I can copy the code)
- Is there a way to export the code for the 'Get New Access Token' thing which seems to be nicely displayed as a GUI thing but I'm sure there are several things happening in the back end with the Auth URL and the Access Token URL.  This might be handy if I'm able to use Google Sheets.

Any pointers on what I should try next?  Or is this pretty much not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Rich (see other answer/comments) who pointed me in the right direction.  This is the exact code which I ended up with which provided me the resulting JSON from Sharesight.

I (stupidly) didn't realise that I was meant to pass my client ID and client secret to the Access Token URL first to get the Access Token, before I pass that as a header to the actual report API that I want to run.

Next steps is to work out how to get the JSON fields into a spreadsheet format in Google Sheets!

```
function getReport() 
{
  var client_id = 'XXX'
  var client_secret = 'YYY'

  var url = 'https://edge-api.sharesight.com/oauth2/token?'
  + '&grant_type=client_credentials'
  + '&client_id=' + client_id
  + '&client_secret=' + client_secret

  var token = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{method:'POST',muteHttpExceptions: true});
  var token_data = JSON.parse(token.getContentText());
  var access_token = token_data.access_token

  var url2 = 'https://edge-api.sharesight.com/api/v2/portfolios/343835/performance.json?'
  var report = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url2,{method:'GET',headers:{Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token}});
  Logger.log(report)

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(report); 
}
```

Comment: If anyone can help me extract data in the JSON object into a matrix table in Google Sheets - that would be much appreciated! I've created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550551/how-to-split-nested-arrays-in-a-json-into-a-table-in-google-sheets-using-javasc

Answer (score 2):

The 'code' grant type is only really suitable for a browser based app.

You should be able to do a 'password' grant type which doesn't require a redirect:

```
  var url = 'https://portfolio.sharesight.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=' 
    + clientId 
    + '&username=' + username + '&password=' + password;

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,  { method: 'POST', muteHttpExceptions: true} );
  Logger.log("authorize response: " + response.getResponseCode() 
    + "; " + response.getContentText());

  var responseMsg = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```

`responseMsg.access_token` and `responseMsg.refresh_token` should then be populated. You can use these to make any API call in Sharesight, e.g. from a user defined function in your spreadsheet.

Obviously you need to get your credentials into your script - I did this with a dialog in Google Sheets.

Alternatively (I haven't tested this in Google Sheets) you can do a 'client_credentials' grant - for this you need to first contact Sharesight support and have your client id associated with your user, and then you can connect with just the client id and secret.

(See https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/)

Comment: Cheers mate, interesting! So you are saying I can hard-code my password (where you have &password) and just get details from there?  If so, (this may be a dumb question), but if the Google Sheet is private, is my password to Sharesight going to be safely hidden in my Google Sheets?  e.g. when it does the API call/communication, does it get 'exposed' out anywhere for people to intercept?  I should have some free time on the weekend so I'll work on it and report back!

Comment: You have to either ask the user interactively for the password or hard code it.

Anything you have in the Google sheet should be private to you and Google (https protects it between Google and Sharesight).

For your use case, you may be better off with the 'client_credentials' grant where you only put the client id and secret in the sheet.

(If Google provided an API in App Script to get a JWT (Json Web Token) for the current Google user, that would be much better, but AFAIK they don't).

Comment: Okay so I've made some good progress - thanks for your help so far!  However, I think I'm having trouble actually doing the POST to return the JSON object.  My code is currently:

function getReport() {
  var client_id = ‘XXXX’
  var client_secret = ‘YYY’
  var url = 'https://edge-api.sharesight.com/api/v2/portfolios/343835/performance.json?'
  + '&grant_type=client_credentials'
  + '&client_id=' + client_id
  + '&client_secret=' + client_secret
  
  //var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{method:'POST'})
  Logger.log(url)
}

Comment: And I know the URL works because when I paste into the browser, it returns a whole bunch of JSON text.  But I'm not sure how I 'run' the URL in GoogleSheets and return the JSON object?  I have a line in there where I was trying to run it (but have commented it out) because I kept getting an error:  
Request failed for https://edge-api.sharesight.com/api/v2/portfolios/343835/performance.json?&grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=XXX&client_secret=YYY returned code 404. Truncated server response: {"status":404,"error":"Not Found"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: Okay I'm pretty sure it's because it's meant to be a GET method (silly me) - will try again after I'm locked out!

Comment: Okay it worked!! Thanks @Rich I'll post the actual code in a new post.  Now I just need to work out how to extract certain JSON fields and put them into a table in Google Sheets

Answer (score 1):

You already have your answer but thought I would share this in case it assists anyone else. This code grabs a token, and stores it for 30 minutes to avoid re-requesting the token without need. Disclaimer - my coding skills are rather basic.

I put this and the rest of the code to parse the JSON and feed it into Google sheets up on my site: https://www.callofthesky.com/import-data-from-sharesight-to-google-sheets/

First define our variables

```
var ClientID = "CLIENT_ID_GOES_HERE";
var ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET_GOES_HERE";
var PortfolioNumber = "PORTFOLIO_NUMBER_GOES_HERE"
```

The next function returns the token. If there is one less than 30 minutes old in the Properties Service it returns it, otherwise it fetches a fresh one from Sharesight.

```
function gettoken() {

  var authdetails = {
    "grant_type" : "client_credentials", 
    "client_id" : ClientID,
    "client_secret" : ClientSecret
  };

  var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'payload' : authdetails
  };

  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var issuetime = scriptProperties.getProperty('issuedtime');

  if (issuetime !== null) { 
    var TokenExpiry = (Number(issuetime) + 1800); }
  else {
    var TokenExpiry = 0;
  }

  var d = new Date();
  var timeStamp = d.getTime();

  if (timeStamp > TokenExpiry) {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.sharesight.com/oauth2/token" , options);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var token = data.access_token;
  addtoproperties(token)
  } 

  else { 
    var token = scriptProperties.getProperty('SStoken');
  }

  return token
}
```

The following function is called by gettoken(). It adds the token that it gets fed and the current time to the Properties Service

```
function addtoproperties(SStoken) {
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  scriptProperties.setProperty('SStoken', SStoken);

  var d = new Date();
  var timeStamp = d.getTime();

  scriptProperties.setProperty('issuedtime', timeStamp);

  var store = scriptProperties.getProperties();

  return;
}
```