# How to split nested arrays in a JSON into a table in Google Sheets (using Javascript?)

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've finally connected via OAuth2 to pull a JSON of a performance report (of shares) and I'm wondering how I can load this object into Google Sheets so it's in a matrix format?

```
{
    "id": "ID-23035",
    "total_gain": 11795.72,
    "holdings": 
     [
        {
            "symbol": "APX",
            "total_gain": 11525.72,
        },
        {
            "symbol": "MP1",
            "total_gain": 270,
        }
    ]
}
```

The whole JSON is stored in a **report** object.

I know how to extract the 'id' and the 'total gain' from the 1st two rows, using:

```
  var id= report_data.id
  var total_gain = report_data.total_gain
```

However I'd like to take the holdings component, i.e.

```
  var holdings = report_data.holdings
```

And then import it into Google Sheets in a matrix style table - to make it look like:

```
|-----symbol-----|----total gain-----|

|------APX-------|-----11525.72------|

|------MP1-------|--------270--------|
```

Is there some sort of code/function/script that can loop through and create this matrix/table?  I'm guessing Google App Script uses JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple for-loop to convert it into a 2 Dimentional array or Array.map

```
var arr2D = holdings.map(function(e){
          return [e.symbol,e.total_gain]});
```

- [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [For-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
- [setValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly for the 2 x 2 data! Now I need to also work out how to change it so it dynamically changes based on how many 'stocks' I have in the JSON.  I'm guessing I can do some sort of JSON count and then set the range of the cells to edit?  My code currently is:

  var arr2D = holdings.map(function(e){
          return [e.symbol,e.total_gain]});
          
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A8:B9");          
  range.setValues(arr2D);

Comment: @dsnO Read the references. My code will dynamically change based on number of stocks. No need to count, unless if you want to go through the for-loop method.

Comment: Thanks!!! Perfect - this works beautifully. Luckily I didn't try and find some sort of counting function. Cheers @I'-'I  P.S.  Hope you don't mind I edited your comment to include the final code (I'm not sure what the proper etiquette is for this sort of stuff (?))

Comment: (I have moved an edit from the question author to its own CW post).

Answer (score 2):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

This is the resulting code I used. Note that I have ended up returning 3 fields so the colNumber changed from 2 to 3.

```
  var arr2D = holdings.map(function(e){
          return [e.symbol,e.name, e.total_gain]});
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(8,1,arr2D.length,3)       
  range.setValues(arr2D);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set headers in google sheet with the name symbol and total_gain ,then make data key-pairs with symbol with their total_gain value, now you can directly insert the data in the sheet.

```
var data = {
    "id": "ID-23035",
    "total_gain": 11795.72,
    "holdings": 
     [
        {
            "symbol": "APX",
            "total_gain": 11525.72,
        },
        {
            "symbol": "MP1",
            "total_gain": 270,
        }
    ]
}  

var formatdata =[];
    data.holdings.forEach(function(val,index){  
      formatdata[val.symbol] = val.total_gain; 
    });
    console.log(formatdata)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently working on a solution based on the other comments. Just wondering if this solution you posted accounts for if I have multiple data points per symbol? e.g. I have only listed 'total gain' but I might choose to add a few more.  Also would it be easy to insert the 'formatdata' into cells in Google Sheet?

Comment: Actually nvm - appreciate your help - but it looks like the other solution above has worked for me already!

Comment: You can extend data as per your requirement and set the respective headers in the sheets

Answer (score 1):

```js
data = {
    "id": "ID-23035",
    "total_gain": 11795.72,
    "holdings": 
     [
        {
            "symbol": "APX",
            "total_gain": 11525.72,
        },
        {
            "symbol": "MP1",
            "total_gain": 270,
        }
    ]
}

let TwoDArray =  data.holdings.map(({symbol, total_gain})=> [symbol, total_gain])
console.log(TwoDArray)
```